# JPA query on abstract class + subclass field condition

Tags: inheritance, jpa, abstract

I have a persistence model like this one :

```
@Entity
public abstract class Employee {
    @Id
    protected Integer employeeId;
    ...
}
@Entity
public class FullTimeEmployee extends Employee {
    protected Integer salary;
    ...
}
@Entity
public class PartTimeEmployee extends Employee {
    protected Float hourlyWage;
}
```

I would like to query Employees with somes children class conditions, for example : salary > 1000.

I tried this but not working.

```
SELECT e
FROM Employee e
WHERE e.salary > 1000;

SELECT e
FROM Employee e
WHERE (TYPE(e) = FullTimeEmployee AND e.salary > 1000)
OR TYPE(e) = PartTimeEmployee;
```

I also tried to put an abstract method in Employee and use it in the query but not working either.

Could you help me please ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Ok, I found a solution. I don't think it is the best because of multiples joins in the final native query. But it is working.

```
SELECT e
FROM Employee e, FullTimeEmployee f, PartTimeEmployee p
WHERE (e = f AND f.salary > 1000)
OR (e = p ...);
```

**EDIT:**

Found another solution which is a **LOT** faster than the one above with 200k rows. Using nested selects in the where clause :

```
SELECT e
FROM Employee e
WHERE e.employeeId IN (SELECT f.employeeId FROM FullTimeEmployee f WHERE f.salary > 1000)
OR e.employeeId IN (SELECT p.employeeId FROM PartTimeEmployee p WHERE ...)
```

**EDIT²:**

It seems that I don't need to do join anymore with last version of Hibernate (currently 4.3.10.Final).

```
SELECT e
FROM Employee e
WHERE e.salary IS NULL
OR e.salary > 1000
```

should work

Comment: Great solutions. Second is specially useful in my case, where I already had two separate queries written but had to put them together into one.

Answer (score 1):

8 years and 11 months later I am having the same issue. Tried all of your approaches, every time I get an error message stating that the **product** table does not exist.
My product class is abstract, so it does not exist in fact, but I have multiple tables extending the **product** and their tables exist.

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public abstract class Product {
...
}
```

**If anybody reads this nowadays, any way to query all of the child tables by performing just one query on the abstract parent table ?**

Comment: Hi, thanks for contributing to SO! This is best asked as a new question.